# Unable to add path to .bashrc in circleci docker image

Tags: docker, circleci-2.0

I am trying to install `conda` inside a circleci docker image and add it to the `.bashrc` file.
Here're some relevant portions from `/.circleci/config.yml`:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.5
    environment:
      BASH_ENV: /home/circleci/.bashrc
      DISTRIB: "conda"
      PYTHON_VERSION: "3.5"
      NUMPY_VERSION: "*"
      SCIPY_VERSION: "*"
      SCIKIT_LEARN_VERSION: "*"
      MATPLOTLIB_VERSION: "*"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
      - run: chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh && ~/miniconda.sh -b
      - run: echo "export PATH=/home/circleci/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: echo $PATH  # Added for troubleshooting.
```

However here is the output I get:

```
====>> echo "export PATH=/home/circleci/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" >> $BASH_ENV
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
echo "export PATH=/home/circleci/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" >> $BASH_ENV
====>> echo $PATH
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So the path to conda is not getting added to `.bashrc`.

How do I solve this? I am at my wits end.
This is supposed to work.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from CircleCI Support. Posting it here for anyone else who comes to SO looking for help:

Please not the default behavior of the shell is non-login meaning the the .bashrc file is not read.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#default-shell-options

You can change the default shell to /bin/sh -eo --login pipefail

You could also use BASH_ENV alternatively.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#using-bash_env-to-set-environment-variables